Issue with logEmailOnSend on the emailSimple api route
I'm trying to login the email with the logEmailOnSend option on true and a recipient id. When the logEmailOnSend is turn off everything works fine. Maybe the relatedRecordId isn't the right one but i guess i would an error that says that the id hasn't been find.
Here is the code :
{
  "inputs" : [
        {
            "emailAddresses" : "abc@gmail.com",
            "emailBody" : "this is a test",
            "emailSubject" : "this is a test",
            "senderType" : "CurrentUser",
            "logEmailOnSend": true,
            "relatedRecordId": "aaaa"
        }
    ]
}

Here is the error :
[
    {
        "actionName": "emailSimple",
        "errors": [
            {
                "statusCode": "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION",
                "message": "An error occurred. Try again, or contact Salesforce Customer Support and provide this error ID: 316083723-335873 (1125190724)",
                "fields": []
            }
        ],
        "isSuccess": false,
        "outputValues": null,
        "version": 1
    }
]

